# Could not find gem 'puma (~> 5.0)' in locally installed gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gemfile

After running bundler in the home directory of my Rails 5 app, I am unable to start `rails server`. As a note, I cannot locate a local installation of the puma gem, 'puma (~> 5.0)', which I thought may be causing the problem.

Comment: What is the output of `gem query --local`? What command are you using to try and start rails server, for example `rails server puma`, `bundle exec puma`, etc.?

Comment: Also, what versions of Rails and Ruby are you using? It would definitely help to know what commands you are running after `bundle` and include the backtrace from any failed executions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on Debian-based Linux (and logged in as an user), after getting into the directory of your Rails app do:
sudo gem install puma -v 5.0

This will prompt you to enter your Linux password. Once you do that, this version of puma will be installed, which should solve this issue.

I faced the same issue, and it worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

I am also stuck on this problem

I am stuck on

```
rails new demo
```

and it gives me

[error which I got on creating a new rails project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkxd3.png)

as @rantingonrails asked

```
gem query --local
```

is giving

> `$ gem query --local WARNING:  query command is deprecated. It will be removed in Rubygems 4. WARNING:  It is recommended that you use` gem search`or`gem list` instead.
> abbrev (default: 0.1.0)
> actioncable (7.0.2.3)
> actionmailbox (7.0.2.3)
> actionmailer (7.0.2.3)
> actionpack (7.0.2.3)
> actiontext (7.0.2.3)
> actionview (7.0.2.3)
> activejob (7.0.2.3)
> activemodel (7.0.2.3)
> activerecord (7.0.2.3)
> activestorage (7.0.2.3)
> activesupport (7.0.2.3)
> addressable (2.8.0)
> base64 (default: 0.1.1)
> benchmark (default: 0.2.0)
> bigdecimal (default: 3.1.1)
> builder (3.2.4)
> bundle (0.0.1)
> bundler (default: 2.3.10)
> capybara (3.36.0)
> cgi (default: 0.3.1)
> childprocess (4.1.0)
> concurrent-ruby (1.1.10)
> crass (1.0.6)
> csv (default: 3.2.2)
> date (default: 3.2.2)
> debug (1.4.0)
> delegate (default: 0.2.0)
> did_you_mean (default: 1.6.1)
> digest (default: 3.1.0)
> drb (default: 2.1.0)
> english (default: 0.7.1)
> erb (default: 2.2.3)
> error_highlight (default: 0.3.0)
> erubi (1.10.0)
> etc (default: 1.3.0)
> fcntl (default: 1.0.1)
> fiddle (default: 1.1.0)
> fileutils (default: 1.6.0)
> find (default: 0.1.1)
> forwardable (default: 1.3.2)
> getoptlong (default: 0.1.1)
> git (1.10.2)
> globalid (1.0.0)
> i18n (1.10.0)
> importmap-rails (1.0.3)
> io-console (default: 0.5.11)
> io-nonblock (default: 0.1.0)
> io-wait (default: 0.2.1)
> ipaddr (default: 1.2.4)
> irb (default: 1.4.1)
> jbuilder (2.11.5)
> json (default: 2.6.1)
> logger (default: 1.5.0)
> loofah (2.16.0)
> mail (2.7.1)
> marcel (1.0.2)
> matrix (0.4.2)
> method_source (1.0.0)
> mini_mime (1.1.2)
> minitest (5.15.0)
> mutex_m (default: 0.1.1)
> net-ftp (0.1.3)
> net-http (default: 0.2.0)
> net-imap (0.2.3)
> net-pop (0.1.1)
> net-protocol (0.1.3, default: 0.1.2)
> net-smtp (0.3.1)
> nio4r (2.5.8)
> nkf (default: 0.1.1)
> nokogiri (1.13.3 x64-mingw-ucrt)
> observer (default: 0.1.1)
> open-uri (default: 0.2.0)
> open3 (default: 0.1.1)
> openssl (default: 3.0.0)
> optparse (default: 0.2.0)
> ostruct (default: 0.5.2)
> pathname (default: 0.2.0)
> power_assert (2.0.1)
> pp (default: 0.3.0)
> prettyprint (default: 0.1.1)
> prime (0.1.2)
> pstore (default: 0.1.1)
> psych (default: 4.0.3)
> public_suffix (4.0.6)
> racc (default: 1.6.0)
> rack (2.2.3, 1.6.13)
> rack-test (1.1.0)
> rails (7.0.2.3)
> rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
> rails-html-sanitizer (1.4.2)
> railties (7.0.2.3)
> rake (13.0.6)
> rbs (2.1.0)
> rchardet (1.8.0)
> rdoc (default: 6.4.0)
> readline (default: 0.0.3)
> regexp_parser (2.2.1)
> reline (default: 0.3.0)
> resolv (default: 0.2.1)
> resolv-replace (default: 0.1.0)
> rexml (3.2.5)
> rinda (default: 0.1.1)
> rss (0.2.9)
> ruby (0.1.0)
> ruby2_keywords (default: 0.0.5)
> rubygems-update (3.3.10)
> rubyzip (2.3.2)
> securerandom (default: 0.1.1)
> selenium-webdriver (4.1.0)
> set (default: 1.0.2)
> shellwords (default: 0.1.0)
> singleton (default: 0.1.1)
> sprockets (4.0.3)
> sprockets-rails (3.4.2)
> sqlite3 (1.4.2)
> stimulus-rails (1.0.4)
> stringio (default: 3.0.1)
> strscan (default: 3.0.1)
> tempfile (default: 0.1.2)
> test-unit (3.5.3)
> thor (1.2.1)
> time (default: 0.2.0)
> timeout (default: 0.2.0)
> tmpdir (default: 0.1.2)
> tsort (default: 0.1.0)
> turbo-rails (1.0.1)
> typeprof (0.21.2)
> tzinfo (2.0.4)
> un (default: 0.2.0)
> uri (default: 0.11.0)
> weakref (default: 0.1.1)
> webdrivers (5.0.0)
> websocket-driver (0.7.5)
> websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
> win32ole (default: 1.8.8)
> xpath (3.2.0)
> yaml (default: 0.2.0)
> zeitwerk (2.5.4)
> zlib (default: 2.1.1)```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).